# jaxl after send message callback

Tags: php, xmpp, xmpphp

I want execute some code after a message has already sent in jaxl. 
which callback is appropriate for this situation?

```
    public function test() {

        require_once 'JAXL/jaxl.php';
        global $client;

        $client = new JAXL(array(
            'jid' => 'user@localhost',
            'pass' => 'password',
            'log_level' => JAXL_INFO
        ));

        $client->add_cb('on_stream_features', function($stanza)  {
            global $client,$thisObj;
            $client->send_chat_msg('otherUser@localhost','Message');  
        });

       $client->add_cb('on_message_send',function(){  //some thing like this
         //some code
       });
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Jaxl library currently doesn't support such callbacks. This is because when you call `$client->send_chat_msg()`, [XMPPStream](https://github.com/abhinavsingh/JAXL/blob/v3.x/xmpp/xmpp_stream.php) queues [XMPPMsg](https://github.com/abhinavsingh/JAXL/blob/v3.x/xmpp/xmpp_msg.php) object in the output buffer of underlying [JAXLSocketClient](https://github.com/abhinavsingh/JAXL/blob/v3.x/core/jaxl_socket_client.php). Output buffers are flushed as and when socket is ready for write.

Before queuing all [XMPPStanza](https://github.com/abhinavsingh/JAXL/blob/v3.x/xmpp/xmpp_stanza.php)'s are serialised (`to_string()`) by `XMPPStream`, thus underlying `JAXLSocketClient` output buffers have no knowledge about which stanza is being flushed over the write ready socket. As a result no such callbacks are currently possible.

There are non-authoritative ways of performing check about delivery status of your message e.g. is the output buffer empty? But this is tricky and not a perfect solution.

Perfect way to implement such callbacks will be to maintain output buffers within the context of `XMPPStream`, which should then be notified about underlying socket write ready state, finally before flushing stanza's over the socket, `XMPPStream` can execute these callbacks. Unfortunately, this is not how the library is designed. Though, possibilities are that such callbacks might get supported in future version of the library.

Comment: thank you for your answer.
I want to send a message and after that disconnect the stream.
what do you have any suggestion for this situation?

Comment: Simply queue your message by calling `$client->send_chat_msg();` and then you can immediately queue XMPP stream ending packet (i.e. disconnect your client) by calling `$client->send_end_stream();`. Also don't forget to register callback for `on_disconnect` event. Once you have received that callback, you are sure that your message stanza was sent. Jaxl library ensures in-order message forwarding i.e. as message packet was queued before stream end packet, it will guarantee they are sent in the same order. Hence you won't receive `on_disconnect` callback until your message stanza has been sent.